# MS SQL server StoreProcedure retornando resultset

Tags: php, sql-server

Sou novo no SQL server e estou precisando criar uma SP que faça o processamento de determinadas tabelas e grave alterações e após me de o resultado destas alterações como uma table-value function para o PHP.
tentei isso :

```
        create procedure auto_fill_teste
    as
    begin
        DECLARE @temp_table table(qtd int);

        insert into @temp_table 
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sysobjects;

        insert into @temp_table 
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sysindexes;    

        SELECT * FROM @temp_table;
    end
```

e no php tenho os seguintes codigos

```
    <?
    class MsSQLConnection {
        protected $MSconn;
        protected $serverName = 'localhost';
        protected $connectionOptions = array("Database" => "master", "UID" => "as", "PWD" => "123456");
        public $query;

        function conecta_MSSQL() {
            $this->MSconn = sqlsrv_connect($this->serverName, $this->connectionOptions);
            if (!$this->MSconn) {
                var_dump(sqlsrv_errors());
                die;
            }
        }

        function executar($sql,$params = array(),$options = array("Scrollable" => "buffered")) {
            if (!$this->MSconn) {
                $this->conecta_MSSQL();
            }       
            $this->query=sqlsrv_prepare($this->MSconn, $sql, $params, $options);
            sqlsrv_execute( $this->query );

        }

        function arrayx($a = null) {
            if (empty($a))
                $a = $this->query;      
            return sqlsrv_fetch_array($a, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH);
        }
    }


    $conexao = new MsSQLConnection();

    $conexao->conecta_MSSQL();

    $conexao->executar("Exec dbo.auto_fill_teste");

    while($row = $conexao->arrayx(NULL)){
        print_r("$row <br>");
    }
    ?>
```

Contudo não eh retornado nada;
ja se eu rodar o comando no manager studio ele retorna o resultset da **temp_table** como esperado.

Comment: No management studio ele retorna o que? 3 selects? O que muda de consultas normais para SP é que vc precisa tratar os multiplos retornos.

Comment: retorna somente 1 resultset com duas linhas

Comment: algo como isso https://1drv.ms/f/s!AphQIPpEhRqggSY3heCZ7jQ0bzv7

Answer (score 1):

Inicialmente colocaria um parâmetro em `arrayx()` para tratar o retorno da SP. Use a função `sqlsrv_next_result()` para saber se existe algo retornado pelo banco, caso sim faça o `fetch_array()` de todos os itens e retorne ao final da função.

```
function arrayx($a = null, $sp = false) {
    if (empty($a)) $a = $this->query; 

    if($sp){
        $next_result = sqlsrv_next_result($a);
        $itens = array();
        if($next_result){
            while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($a, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $itens[] = $row;
            }
        }

        return $itens;
    }       
    return sqlsrv_fetch_array($a, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH);
}
```

A chama deve ficar assim:

```
$conexao = new MsSQLConnection();
$conexao->conecta_MSSQL();
$conexao->executar("Exec dbo.auto_fill_teste");
$result = $conexao->arrayx(NULL, true);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Achei!!! o sql server retorna um resultset pra cada comando dentro da SP,
isso tbm incluem os insert/updates/deletes entre outros, informando a quantidade de linhas afetadas.

para isso tem que ir navegando entre os resultssets como no link
http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-next-result.php

para funcionar minha gambiarra,quer dizer,meu código ficou assim:

```
<?
class MsSQLConnection {
    protected $MSconn;
    protected $serverName = 'localhost';
    protected $connectionOptions = array("Database" => "master", "UID" => "as", "PWD" => "123456");
    public $query;

    function conecta_MSSQL() {
        $this->MSconn = sqlsrv_connect($this->serverName, $this->connectionOptions);
        if (!$this->MSconn) {
            var_dump(sqlsrv_errors());
            die;
        }
    }

    function executar($sql,$params = array(),$options = array("Scrollable" => "buffered")) {
        if (!$this->MSconn) {
            $this->conecta_MSSQL();
        }       
        $this->query=sqlsrv_prepare($this->MSconn, $sql, $params, $options);
        sqlsrv_execute( $this->query );

    }

    function arrayx($a = null) {
        if (empty($a))
            $a = $this->query;      
        return sqlsrv_fetch_array($a, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH);
    }

    function  proximoResultset($a = null){
        if (empty($a))
            $a = $this->query;
        return sqlsrv_next_result($a);
    }
}


$conexao = new MsSQLConnection();

$conexao->conecta_MSSQL();

$conexao->executar("Exec dbo.auto_fill_teste");

while ($conexao->proximoResultset()) {
    while ($row = $conexao->arrayx(NULL, "both")) {
        print_r("$row[0] <br>");
    }
}
    ?>
```

Com isso ele foi pulando os resultado de insert e quando chegou no RS que eu queria ele impimiu os valores do select